# Integrate Roxy Filemanager From Another Previous Directory With Tinymce

Tags: path, directory, tinymce, integration

Path to My JS file calling Tinymce Into My Page

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\seller\js\functions.js

Using This JS

```js
tinymce.init({
    selector: "textarea[name=\"content\"] ",
    plugins: [
        "advlist autolink lists link image charmap print preview anchor",
        "searchreplace visualblocks code fullscreen",
        "insertdatetime media table contextmenu paste"
    ],
    toolbar: "insertfile undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image", file_browser_callback: RoxyFileBrowser
});
var roxyFileman = 'fileman/index.html?integration=tinymce4';

function RoxyFileBrowser(field_name, url, type, win) {
  var roxyFileman = 'fileman/index.html';
  if (roxyFileman.indexOf("?") < 0) {     
    roxyFileman += "?type=" + type;   
  }
  else {
    roxyFileman += "&type=" + type;
  }
  roxyFileman += '&input=' + field_name + '&value=' + win.document.getElementById(field_name).value;
  if(tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language){
    roxyFileman += '&langCode=' + tinyMCE.activeEditor.settings.language;
  }
  tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
     file: roxyFileman,
     title: 'Roxy Fileman',
     width: 850, 
     height: 650,
     resizable: "yes",
     plugins: "media",
     inline: "yes",
     close_previous: "no"  
  }, {     window: win,     input: field_name    });
  return false; 
}
```

But My Roxy fileman is located

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myapp\fileman

Which is one directory back from tinymce. So, i want to know how can i access fileman in tinymce.
I tried this:

> var roxyFileman = '../fileman/index.html?integration=tinymce4';

Thanks!